# How to customize Laravel websockets connections (via handler)

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, ratchet

I use laravel websockets package ([Beyondcode](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/introduction) pusher replacement) with Laravel echo and everything is working as expected. What i am trying to achieve is to customize my connections - to check when clients interrupt their connections (closing browser) and execute events on opening and closing connections. I'm trying to extend the websocket handler (as mentioned in the docs) but i cannot access the objects that i need to (for e.g. User).
Is there any way to do this ? The main purpose is to lock an order while it is being processed ( opened in the browser ) and unlock it when it is finished ( being closed from the browser )

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do it by myself. I don't think that my solution is the right one , but i used channels to extract the object properties and execute new event to other clients in onClose function.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).